# Using Arcpy to Turn on Maplex Label Engine

Tags: arcpy, maplex

I've been attempting to automate a number of processes into one script using arcpy. I've got everything working and am wondering if there's a way to use arcpy to toggle on/off the Maplex Label Engine.

So far I haven't been able to find an appropriate answer. Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see a way to define or change the label engine from Arcpy or the system registry. However, an mxd seems to preserve the Label Engine choice on the Labeling toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to do this is through ArcObjects. The [IMap.AnnotationEngine property](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000m8q000000) can be used to get or set the label engine.

As Arcpy is a subset of ArcObjects, this particular property has not been implemented at the moment. I can't see Esri adding it any time soon, as Arcpy is supposed to be a reduced set of features and they are very reluctant to add anything else.