# Changing label placement (anchor point) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling

arcpy let user automatically turn on the label, use label expression to save our time. is there a way how to change the position of the label like we use to do on label properties like screenshot below ?

[image]

so if i want to change the label placement/position of 100 layers, even i can use arcpy to turn on and use label expression using arcpy, i still have to double click into layer properties to change the label placement anyway?

i assumed there is away to solve that, any suggestion?

what i need to do is put the label in top of the point feature, but the default is on the top right of the feature.

Comment: This is beyond what python can do alone, you will need to use ArcObjects to alter the label placement properties for a layers' label class. If you think you can manage ArcObjects I could try to track down a method using ArcObjects to point you in the right direction. Do you also need to account for Maplex label placement?

Comment: well i have figured another workaround as someone had describe before in this forum, i convert the label into annotation (which my final purpose should be in annotation form), then using model builder and iterate, i will iterate for every layers that i use, and use field calculator to fill the value for fields named "xoffset" and "yoffset" and change to the value i want, but if you have easier way i happy to listen , thank you

Comment: btw ive tried using maplex label, but still yu have to click each layer , cant do automatically for all layers label, i really want to skip the repitition works like we use to do with arcpy and model builder

Comment: If it works then put it in as an answer. Considering annotation was your goal it fits this solution, there is a limit to what you can do with labels via arcpy and Maplex would be extra complexity.. I find Maplex beneficial where half an hour of modifying rules prior to conversion saves hours of moving annotation manually or where annotation isn't an option; Maplex produces labels with better placement options and avoidance rules but there is no way to turn it on in arcpy https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180039/using-arcpy-to-turn-on-maplex-label-engine

Answer (score 0):

well i have figured another workaround as someone had describe before in this forum,

i convert the label into annotation (which my final purpose should be in annotation form), then i will iterate for every layers that i use using model builder, inside model builder i use field calculator to fill the value for fields named "xoffset" and "yoffset" and change to the value i want.

Comment: Was the previous Q&A that helped you this one (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65959/moving-offsetting-point-locations-using-modelbuilder-or-arcpy) or another?  Whenever, you refer to other Q&As in posts here please provide links to them.